# Error connecting to socket channels when running a echo server through a subdomain

Tags: laravel, nginx, websocket, laravel-echo, broadcasting

> A lot of companies or work places have secutiry protocols in place where only the common ports are open, e.g. 80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS). If we were to have our web app try connecting to port 6001 (by default of laravel-echo-server), definitely some of your users will encounter problems as the port is closed... [Source](http://bloggie.io/@jctan/laravel-websocket-echo-server-ionic)

After creating a subdomain in nginx, I launched sockets through it and it worked, except that now I can’t connect to any channel. `Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 419`*"message": "CSRF token mismatch.",*

Experimentally disabled csrf protection and the error changed to `Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403` *"message": "",*

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Port configured on proxy server (default: 6001).
 * The default port for HTTPS protocol is 443.
 *
 * @type {string}
 */
const ECHO_DOMAIN = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'ws.site.com'
    : 'wsdev.site.com';

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: `https://${ECHO_DOMAIN}`,
        reconnectionAttempts: 120
    });
...
```

**successful connection**
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding a variable **SESSION_DOMAIN=.site.com** in **.env**, wich changes value in **'domain'** in **config/session.php**

Then you need to clear cookies in browser, and the cache on server. *You may also need to do **composer dump-autoload**.* [Primary source](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/68#issuecomment-464346513)